How to fix "uploadDate" timezone for vimeo embed video?
I have vimeo embedded video in one of my web page. Google is automatically adding structured data for this and showing warning "Datetime property 'uploadDate' is missing a timezone". How to fix this ?
In rich result text showing all valid,  "uploadDate":"2023-11-14T05:15:06-05:00"
